# How to convert timestamps to time ago format in react?

Tags: javascript

suppose that I have an creating time in this format : (2021-06-30 15:36:50.375+03), and I wanna convert it to time ago format like 5 min ago or 2 hours ago , so how can I do that in javascript (react)?

Comment: You can subtract dates. If the string is parseable: `new Date() - new Date("2021-06-30 15:36:50.375+03")` will give you the difference in milliseconds. Divide by 60000 to get minutes. (also, both react and postgresql are irrelevant here)

Comment: Main rules when writing a question: 1st -> always show some codes of what you did, or some codes surrounding or appearing before of what you want to achieve. 2nd -> format codes or output when you can. Example of the 2 Like: `const data = { created_at = '2021-06-30 15:36:50.375+03' };` and `console.log(timeAgo(data.created_at)); // should print like 5 min ago or 2 hours ago`

Comment: check day.js plugins

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doing it by yourself will require a lot of codes, continuous fixing and improvement. You can either use a code snippet of another coder, or better you can use some JS (React/Node/etc.) npm packages, like `moment` https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment . The advantage of moment is that it's maintained, high quality and very popular, 16M downloads a week, 45.8K stars in Github.

As an example, moment uses the method `fromNow()`:

```
import moment from 'moment';

// other codes

const timeago = moment(data.created_at).fromNow();
```

**EDIT : (2 packages very light) ----**

If you are using just the `fromNow` feature of Moment package which is heavy and on which tree-shaking doesn't work, and are in need for lighter page size for sep performance, you might wanna use another very light package like: `react-timeago`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-timeago , or `timeago-react`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/timeago-react which are both way lighter than `moment` package.

The `react-timeago` also support automatic update each second, 30s, 60s or any other period specified. Its codes would go like:

```
import TimeAgo from 'react-timeago';

// auto-updated each 60 seconds
return (
  <TimeAgo
    date={comment.created_at}
    component={Text}
    minPeriod={60}
    style={styles.timeAgo}
  />
);
```

I'm using `react-timeago` now. The `timeago-react` is even more lighter, but I didn't tested it yet.

Comment: Have you seen this?  https://dockyard.com/blog/2020/02/14/you-probably-don-t-need-moment-js-anymore

Comment: @blnks That's great tips, I know a lot of way to do this. There is never one solution that fit all cases. But, if you take time, you'll see that the OP is a beginner in date time manipulation. So it's best to start with simple package like moment or other. And when and if he needs to customize later when the App become very successful, then he will have more time, skills and collaborators to achieve it in just days.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. I was going to create a function for that but you just saved me a whole lot of time 

Comment: @ChidiebereEzeokwelume all right. Also do your choice according to your application type. For website aiming loading speed for SEO, Moment JS is not light and has many features in addition to timeago, then you might also use another lighter and package that does only that.